# replace value of array if value exists in other array of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to do array manipulation
Basically I have two arrays that is generated dynamically and can be of any length.

```js
let arr1 =['test', 'XDDD', 'test new']
let arr2 = [{value: 'test', error : 'error'}, {value: 'test new', error: 'invalid'}]
```

I have check if `arr2` object property value exists in `arr1` , if yes then replace the `arr1` value at index. for eg test is at index `0` then replace it like test [error] i.e `arr2.value + arr2.error`. similarly `"test new"`  should get replaced at same index with `"test new [invalid]"`

Final output `['test [error]', 'XDDD', 'test new [invalid]']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using forEach (modifing the arr1) or map (if you want a new array).

```
arr2.forEach(item => { 
    const idx = arr1.findIndex(e => e === item.value);
    if (idx >= 0) {
        arr1[idx] = `${arr1[idx]} [${item.error}]`;
    }
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

```
const newArr = arr1.map(item => {
    const err = arr2.find(a => a.value === item);
    return err ? `${item} [${err.error}]` : item;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1.map(el => {
  const error = arr2.find(a => a.value === el);
  return error ? `${error.value} [${error.error}]` : el;
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.